# How can I create smart contract for forwarding ERC20 with solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I try to to create a contract that receive ERC20 token, then forward to destination address with below code, but it seems like it is not working correctly.

```
receive() external payable
    {
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
        ERC20 token = ERC20(TOKEN_ADDRESS);
        token.transfer(DESTINATION_ADDRESS,token.balanceOf(address(this));
    }
```

- Is there anyway to create contract like this with smartcontract?
- How I can change above code to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to create contract like this with smartcontract?

Yes.

> How I can change above code to make it work?

You need to use `approve()` and `transferFrom()` of ERC-20 token standard to process token payments in smart contracts. `payable` keyword only concerns ETH payments, not token payments.

For more information how `approve()` mechanism work can be for example [found here](https://morioh.com/p/ae4e4123233c), though multiple tutorials exist on this topic.

Comment: For this case, since the sender is actually transferring ERC20 token to the contract. You do not need to run `approve()` and `transferFrom()` transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.
The point that this receive() function is not trigger when sending token to the contract, so this code is not working at all.

And in my case, I think I have to create a contract to let the owner call and use ERC20 transfer function to transfer the token, because he is the token owner already, then he do not need to call approve and transferFrom function.